# How can I split a vector into two halfs in rust?

Tags: rust

I have a vector `Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>`, because I want to split it into many pieces in a recursive function, I need to split one vector into two half parts each time.

Is there a way that can split a vector like this at some index without allocating new memory?

As `Box<dyn SomeTrait>` doesn't have Copy or Clone trait, I guess when splited, the owner of the vector would be changed.

Comment: If you do not need to take ownership of elements of the vector then a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) is probably what you are looking for. You could get a slice to the lower half and to the upper half and pass them to your recursive function.

Comment: @msaw328 Sorry, I just realize what I need is to take the ownership, because box can't be cloned or copied

Comment: This cannot be possible because `Vec`s own their memory and expect it to be all theirs. You can create a wrapper that behave "as if" it was owned (using unsafe code), or using something like `drain()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that can split a vector like this at some index without allocating new memory?

It looks like you need some views (i.e. slices) on the existing vector.
Creating another vector holding some elements from the original one will require a new memory allocation: the heap storage for the elements of the second vector (the boxes themselves, not the objects these boxes point to, these latter won't move).

Here is a trivial example in which *regular* slices taken from the original vector will be problematic (exclusive and shared reference to the original vector at the same time), and a solution using [`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).

Splitting each sub-part recursively (for your specific program) will always refer to the original storage of the initial vector, without any new dynamic allocation.

```rust
trait SomeTrait: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn get_something(&self) -> &str;
    fn change_something(
        &mut self,
        txt: &str,
    );
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {
    text: String,
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
    fn get_something(&self) -> &str {
        self.text.as_str()
    }
    fn change_something(
        &mut self,
        txt: &str,
    ) {
        self.text.push_str(txt);
    }
}

fn some_function(
    head: &[Box<dyn SomeTrait>],
    tail: &mut [Box<dyn SomeTrait>],
) {
    tail.iter_mut().for_each(|elem| {
        if let Some(pos) = head
            .iter()
            .position(|e| e.get_something() == elem.get_something())
        {
            elem.change_something(&format!(" found at {}", pos));
        }
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait>> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..6 {
        v.push(Box::new(SomeStruct {
            text: format!("text {}", i % 3),
        }))
    }
    let mid = v.len() / 2;
    //
    // some_function(&v[0..mid], &mut v[mid..]); // error!
    //
    let (head, tail) = v.split_at_mut(mid);
    some_function(head, tail);
    //
    println!("{:#?}", v);
}
/*
[
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 0",
    },
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 1",
    },
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 2",
    },
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 0 found at 0",
    },
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 1 found at 1",
    },
    SomeStruct {
        text: "text 2 found at 2",
    },
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe I have been confused about the concept "allocating momery" with the `Box`'s ownership transfer...

I just got my answer, it is `Vec::split_off`

It seems that the function will allocate new memory and the original vector's capacity won't be changed.

What's more, the new splited_off vector does own the Boxes!

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off

Comment: The question asks « Is there a way that can split a vector like this at some index without allocating new memory? ». In the documentation of `Vec::split_off()` we can read  (obviously) « Returns a newly allocated vector containing... ». It's like you answered another question here.